# Is it possible that `request.resource.data` in a batched commit contains my subcollection write too?

Tags: firebase-security

I'm getting permission denied errors doing a batched write that makes no sense to me.

I have a collection of `foo` with some rules like this:

```
match /foo/{fooId} {

function onlyHasAllowedFields(data) {
                return data.diff({}).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['availableWithoutSub', 
                                                            'dateAdded', 'dateDeleted', 
                                                            'hasName', 
                                                            'insensitiveName', 'name',
                                                            'userId']);
}

allow create: if (
    ... a lot of functions
    &&
    onlyHasAllowedFields(request.resource.data)
);

allow update: if (
    ... a lot of functions
    &&
    onlyHasAllowedFields(request.resource.data)
);

    match /bar/{barId} {
        allow create: if (
            ... a bunch of functions
        )
   }
```

My `foo` creates work fine, which suggests the `foo` document in the database must only have allowed fields.

When a user changes the name, I do a batched update like this to update the `hasName`, `insensitiveName`, and `name` fields on the main doc and create a new doc in the `bar` subcollection.

```
const updateName = async (newName: string, fooId: string) => {
    const batch = firestore().batch();
    
    // update foo
    const fooData = {
        hasName: newName.length > 0,
        name: newName,
        insensitiveName: newName.toLowerCase(),
    };

    batch.update(db.collection('foo').doc(fooId), fooData);

    // create bar
    const barData = {
        fieldName: 'name',
        fieldValue: newName,
        userId: uid
    }
    batch.set(db
        .collection('foo')
        .doc(fooId)
        .collection('bar')
        .doc(), barData);

    batch.commit();
}
```

This batch commit fails with a permission denied error.

If I comment out the `onlyHasAllowedFields` update clause, then it passes.

Or if I comment out the `batch.set(barData)` in my client code, then it passes.

But setting `bar`'s `allow create:` to `if (true)` still fails.

This is confusing.

I know the existing `foo` doc only contains allowed fields and I know that I'm only updating allowed fields, so `onlyHasAllowedFields` should pass.

All I can think is that `request.resource.data` somehow contains data about the subcollection write too and that's why there's an issue?

**Update** If I change this from running as a batch to running in a transaction, it works.

Comment: So if you comment out the `onlyHasAllowedFields` clause and keep the `batch.set(barData)`, it still works?

Comment: Are you sure your `bar` doc does not already exist? In which case you also need an `update` clause.

Comment: And to answer the question in the title: no, it is not possible, the issue comes from somewhere else

Comment: Yes, if I comment out `onlyHasAllowedFields` and keep `batch.set(barData)` then it works. And yes, I'm certain the `bar` doc does not already exist.

Comment: Test this using the emulator, it will allow you to print debug statements, priceless to for debugging

Comment: I am using the emulator, but I don't know how to print debug statements from my .rules file with it. I didn't see any info on this in the docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite).

Comment: This will save you a lot of time: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.debug